# How to make a function select the last available variable in a matrix/vector in rstudio

Tags: r, function

I am simulating plant growth in r.

Vector A is a 10x1 vector that holds the value for a plant mass. Each row represents an hour. At hour zero, the first row is set to 5 while the remaining 9 are made up of zeros. At each hour interval, a new variable is added to the next available row.

```
A=matrix(nrow=10,ncol=1,0)
A[1]=5 #setting the plant's mass at time zero
```

At each time interval, I want to use the plants mass at the start of the interval as a constant and then re-calculate the new mass at the end of the interval.

I have created a function that uses plant mass from Vector A as a constant as follows:

````
    ```{r} StartRespire=function(A,Respira=66.7,Cgain){ #note Cgain is a constant determined in another loop 
RespCost=A*Respira

if(RespCost>Cgain){
NewA=0

print("Not enough C for respiration. Plant dies")

}

else{

NewA=A*Cgain } 
return(list(NewA=NewA)) 
}
````

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to make the function automatically chose the last non zero value in Vector A?
2. Is there a way to make the function define NewA as the next available value (add to the next row)

Comment: To question 1 - it seems this would be A[1] in all cases as A is not being updated but NewA is.  question 2 -  (in a for loop) NewA[i +1]  = A[i] * Cgain[i]. I rewrote your function to try to get a sense of it as `startRespire <-
function(A, Respira=66.7, Cgain){
RespCost = matrix(nrow=10, ncol=1, 0)
newA = matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 1, 0)
for (i in 1:length(A)) {
RespCost[i] = A[i]*Respira
if(RespCost[i] > Cgain[i]){
newA[i] = 0
print('Not enough C for respiration. Plant dies')[i]
}
else{
newA[i]= A[i] * Cgain[i]
}
}
return(list(newA = newA))
}`
To get results absent Cgain.

Comment: Sorry, using Cgain values `Cgain
 [1] 435.2 435.2 435.2 435.2 435.2  67.7  67.7  67.7  67.7  67.7`. Putting RespCost and newA inside the function needed to deal with scope, these values need to be inside the function to be available.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. Matrix A and the function above is only a small component of the routine as a whole. I was more specifically looking for a way of manipulating the multiple different matrixes than solving this particular section. Due to the nature of the project, I actually specificaly need the matrixes/vectors to be independent of any function and loop.